# Event handling on jQuery this

Tags: jquery, event-handling, keypress

```
function Car(id) {
    var $this = this;

    this.init = function() {
        this.el = document.getElementById(id);
        $(this).on('keypress', function(e){
            alert(e.target);
        });
    }
}
```

The `alert` never happens. If I change `$(this)` to `#hero`. It works. I can't see why.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hero = new Car("hero");
    hero.init();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is obviously `this.el`, while `this` is the parent `init()` function :

```
function Car(id) {
    var $this = this; // you never use this ?

    this.init = function() {
        this.el = document.getElementById(id); // you set it to this.el
        $(this.el).on('keypress', function(e){ // so you should use that for the
            alert(e.target);                   // event handler as well
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var hero = new Car("hero");
    hero.init();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGeQU/)

Of course, this would be more jQuery'ish:

```
this.init = function() {
    $('#' + id).on('keypress', function(e) {
        alert(e.target);                   
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw - I do use $this, but I didn't include more code than necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You are bing the event to the function, bind it to the element.

```
function Car(id) {
    var $this = this;

    this.init = function() {
        this.el = document.getElementById(id);
        $(this.el).on('keypress', function(e){  //changed in this line
            alert(e.target);
        });
    }
}
```